# How to solve "Binary Tree Maximum Path Product"?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

This problem looks much like [Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/) except that **node value can be positive, negative or zero**, and the result should be **Maximum Path Product** rather than Maximum Path Sum.
Can anyone help?

### UPDATE-1:

Here is the classic solution for "Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum":
https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/4407/accepted-short-solution-in-java/2

```
public class Solution {
    int maxValue;

    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        maxPathDown(root);
        return maxValue;
    }

    private int maxPathDown(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return 0;
        int left = Math.max(0, maxPathDown(node.left));
        int right = Math.max(0, maxPathDown(node.right));
        maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, left + right + node.val);
        return Math.max(left, right) + node.val;
    }
}
```

### UPDATE-2:

Here is a naive solution for maximum path product. You can test it [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/) using "Custom Testcase".

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    int maxProduct = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    class Pair{
        int min;
        int max;
        public Pair(int min, int max){
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
    }
    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        helper(root);
        return maxProduct;
    }
    public Pair helper(TreeNode root){
        if(root == null) return new Pair(0, 0);

        Pair left = helper(root.left);
        Pair right = helper(root.right);
        //update global max product
        if(root.val == 0){
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, 0);
        }else{
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * left.min);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * left.max);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * right.min);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * right.max);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * left.min * right.min);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * left.min * right.max);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * left.max * right.min);
            maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, root.val * left.max * right.max);
        }

        int min = 0, max = 0; // if root.val == 0 then , min and max should be 0 both
        //calculate min and max path product including root
        min  = Math.min(min, root.val);
        min  = Math.min(min, root.val * left.min);
        min  = Math.min(min, root.val * left.max);
        min  = Math.min(min, root.val * right.min);
        min  = Math.min(min, root.val * right.max);

        max  = Math.max(max, root.val);
        max  = Math.max(max, root.val * left.min);
        max  = Math.max(max, root.val * left.max);
        max  = Math.max(max, root.val * right.min);
        max  = Math.max(max, root.val * right.max);
        return new Pair(min, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the summary solution for max path sum?  I'd guess the solution for product is very similar, except the summary information you keep instead of a max sum is both a max product and a min product.

Comment: @RobNeuhaus, I have add the solution for max path sum in post. I am thinking keep a pair to tracking min and max of each subtree just as you said, but I think It's tricky to calculate current min and max, is there any elegant way?

Comment: When you hit a 0, there's no point in continuing on that path. That's one optimization

Comment: @cricket_007, yeah, you are right. but it has no effect on the algorithm.

Comment: Scratch the negative piece. Two large negatives make a large positive

Comment: Could you help to implement this algorithm in an elegant way?  @cricket_007

Comment: I don't have a BinaryTree class just sitting around I can use... I would recommend you attempt a solution first in your question as per [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cricket_007, I have added a naive solution which I think is correct, but inelegant.

Comment: If that solution "works", then you should ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cricket_007: Code Review is about testing code that is working as intended. In this case, it is returning the Maximum Path Sum when he needs the Maximum Path Product. As it stands now, this would be Off-Topic on CR.

Comment: @Trojan404 Maybe re-read the question. "Here is a naive solution"

Comment: @cricket_007: As it stands right now, this would be Off-Topic on CR as the OP has said: > result should be Maximum Path Product rather than Maximum Path Sum. If the OP says the code isn't working, we don't review. You're more than welcome to join me in [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) to discuss this further. :)

Comment: I think you need to update your question a bit more. Right now you're saying you want the MPP and aren't getting that. Then you give hypothetical code that does absolutely nothing and then code that all we can assume is doesn't work based on what you've told us. Expand on what you want and what you don't understand. From there, it might be a decent Code Review question. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Trojan404, I want a decent solution for "Binary Tree Maximum Path Product", and BTW, talk is cheap, show me the code please :-)